# Frame-Motion event handler doesn't work in child component with svg path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, framer-motion

I had an issue with Framer Motion in passing the event handler in the child component.

Sandbox below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-svg-checkbox-forked-vgrre?file=/src/Example.tsx

The expected behavior is that when i hover on the black circle, a capsule shape icon will appear. When I move my cursor out of the circle, the capsule shape icon will disappear.
In the example above, the onMouseEnter and onMouseOut doesn't work if i put them in the CircleBackground component. (as I have it now)
But if I move them to the <motion.svg>, then the capsule shape icon will appear when hover on svg container.
But the intention is to have the capsule shape appear only when I hover on the circle, not on the svg container. Because i don't need the animation when hovering on white space.

Hope i made my question clear. Thanks

Comment: please use the following sandbox:   https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-floating-icon-wxipv?file=/src/Example.tsx     Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-q-63601325-68peh?file=/src/Example.tsx:1016-1344) is a possible solution to your problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-q-63601325-68peh?file=/src/Example.tsx:1016-1344

Your `HoverBackground` and `CircleBackground` are covering each other and hence the mouse events are not reaching the child component.

Toggling the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property on the `HoverBackground` solves this:

```
<HoverBackground
        path={editHoverBackground}
        variants={tickVariants}
        style={{
          pathLength,
          opacity,
          pointerEvents: isChecked ? "all" : "none"
        }}
        custom={isChecked}
        location="translate(23,39)"
        onMouseOut={() => setIsChecked(!isChecked)}
      />
```

Comment: Hi itaydafna, thank you for your comment. I was also having trouble adding the event handler into multiple child.  Please see sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-floating-icon-edited-wnzf8?file=/src/Example.tsx        I tried to add another icon that does the same thing as the first one, but I want them to act separately. If I hover on one circle, only one capsule shape will appear. Do you have any suggestions for this? Thanks

Comment: @me-zhang, one direction you can go is treat the entire SVG element as a reusable component. Then you can render it multiple times. Check out this pen for example: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/so-q-63601325-forked-phzmw